# How to change line width of a pandas plot if another variable satisfies a condtition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, series

I want to plot a series of data:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2))
ind = pd.DataFrame({'ind0':np.random.random_integers(0,1, 5), \
                     'ind1':np.random.random_integers(0,1, 5)})



data = pd.concat([s,ind], axis=1)
```

Where the "0" and "1" series are plot and the LINE WIDTH increases for "0" when "ind0" is 1, and likewise for "1".

```
          0         1  ind0  ind1
0  2.029756 -1.211402     1     0
1  0.428830  0.508613     1     0
2  1.964346  1.032110     0     1
3  1.424997 -0.363719     1     0
4 -0.581283  0.774375     1     0
```

Comment: How should the line width change from *point*-based values? Or are you planning to plot with only markers, and you wish to change the markers' linewidths? I'm fairly certain matplotlib supports only a single line width per plot, so in this case you probably have to plot each dataset twice: first `data[0][ind0==0]` with wider lines and `data[0][ind0!=0]` with narrower lines; and same for `data[1]` (or however pandas dataframes can be indexed).

Comment: This is a great point, instead of changing the line width, it might make more sense to use a series of markers.  Any advice how I would get the markers only on the subset in a pythonic way?  Thank you!

Comment: As I said, only plot a subset in a pythonic way. If you columns were the arrays `col0`, `col1`, `ind0`, `ind1`, then you'd have to `plt.plot(col0[ind0==0],'o',linewidth=bigwidth); plt.plot(col0[ind!=0],'o',linewidth=smallwidth)` with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I don't know how pandas dataseries fields can be accessed, but the final indexing should be the same. So the point is just to use a logical mask for your columns, based on `ind0==0`  or `1` and the same for `ind1`.

Comment: I decided to add an answer to make it clear what I mean. Please let me know if it's not what you're after.

Comment: Have you by any chance looked at my answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how pandas `DataFrame`s work on the small scale, but it's enough that they are compatible with numpy `ndarray`s. So I'll assume that you have the latter, as my point is just that you should mask your values based on the variables `ind0` and `ind1`. I suggest using a `plt.plot` with only markers, (or, equivalently, a `plt.scatter`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
s = np.random.randn(n,2)
ind0 = np.random.random_integers(0,1, n)
ind1 = np.random.random_integers(0,1, n)

srange = np.arange(s.shape[0]) # for plotting
trueinds0 = ind0.astype(bool)  # for readibility
trueinds1 = ind1.astype(bool)  # for readibility

lw_wide = 3   # larger linewidth
lw_narrow = 1 # smaller linewidth

hf,ax = plt.subplots()

# plot first column of s with indexing from ind0
ax.plot(srange[trueinds0],s[:,0][trueinds0],'bs',markeredgecolor='blue',markeredgewidth=lw_wide)
ax.plot(srange[np.logical_not(trueinds0)],s[:,0][np.logical_not(trueinds0)],'bs',markeredgecolor='blue',markeredgewidth=lw_narrow)

# plot second column of s with indexing from ind1
ax.plot(srange[trueinds1],s[:,1][trueinds1],'ro',markeredgecolor='red',markeredgewidth=lw_wide)
ax.plot(srange[np.logical_not(trueinds1)],s[:,1][np.logical_not(trueinds1)],'ro',markeredgecolor='red',markeredgewidth=lw_narrow)

#######

# using scatter and two marker sizes:

size_wide = 50
size_narrow = 25

hf,ax = plt.subplots()

# create a single array specifying the marker sizes:
sizes = np.where(trueinds0,size_wide,size_narrow)
opts = {'c':'b','marker':'s','s':sizes,'edgecolors':'face'}
# plot first column of s with indexing from ind0
ax.scatter(srange,s[:,0],**opts)

sizes = np.where(trueinds1,size_wide,size_narrow)
opts = {'c':'r','marker':'o','s':sizes,'edgecolors':'face'}
# plot second column of s with indexing from ind1
ax.scatter(srange,s[:,1],**opts)
```

Due to its more concise form, I suggest using the latter solution, with `scatter`. Result of this with

```
ind0 = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
ind1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

is:

[image: result]